# Are there any disadvantages in buying Outward at GOG.com instead of Steam? Do mods actually work properly in the GOG version?

Tags: steam, gog, outward

I want to buy [*Outward*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outward), and I usually buy games from GOG and avoid supporting Steam if I can. However, I have [read](https://www.gog.com/forum/outward/using_mods_with_outward) that there can be problems with launching Nexus mods with the GOG version.

Is it true? If so, can it be solved?

I don't want to buy the Steam version, but I will have to if the GOG one turns out to be incomplete.

Comment: This is a perfectly objective question.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy - For meta commentary on your post (such as linking to meta policies or blogs like the Good/Bad subjective one you mentioned), putting it in the comments is the general practice here.

Comment: In the thread you linked to someone says "some mods work while others don't", and that's the best answer there is available -- a maybe to both questions.

Comment: The title asks two questions, but the latter seems to be more related to the post.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to install mods for Outward. For the GoG version of the game, you have to first start in the GoG galaxy launcher and convert the game to the mono installation. Epic Games has this enabled by default, and on the Steam version, you go through the beta section. "Properties > Betas > "default-mono - Public default branch (mono)." For the GoG version of the game, you have to click the options button, which should be from the right of the play button. Then you should go to Manage Installation then to Configure, then to the Installation menu. Here you should be able to find a button to set the game to the *default-mono* version. If you see further options make sure to select the highest number for the latest version of the game.

After you have your game set to mono then you have to find some mods. I would recommend using Thunderstore due to the fact that it has a built-in mod launcher as well as having more up-to-date mods. It is highly advised when modding to make a backup of Outward\BepInEx, Outward\Mods, Outward\winhttp.dll, and Outward\doorstop_config.ini. These files are used in a ton of steam games and making sure you have a backup no matter what the game is good practice. Next download r2modman, the mod manager that Thunderstore uses. Choose Outward as your main game, and create a profile for the launcher. Make sure your installation is correct by checking: Settings > Locations > Change Outward directory. Last but not least you download BepInExPack Outward pack in the mod database and any other mods that you please.

The only thing that you must do to play modded is to launch from r2modman, if you want to play vanilla you can either click that option or launch directly from your preferred launcher. There are other methods of modding the game but using r2modman is typically the most reliable.

Comment: And Thunderstore works with both the Steam and GOG versions, as well as the mods themselves? You're not really answering the question — at least not directly.

Comment: Joachim - I guess I interpreted the question to be asking about modding. My intent was to demonstrate that you could mod on the GOG version. I am new to this site, should I edit that in?

Comment: Not that you're new, no, we can see that from your reputation level and the amount of badges. It also doesn't really matter, since it was simply mentioned in the question, and has nothing to do with how we handle things here - except maybe that it's good to know we're not a forum :) If you edit your answer and just focus on the 'moddability' of the GoG version, I think it would be a good answer.